# Could not get unknown property 'localProperties'

Tags: android, gradle

I want to read properties defined in *local.properties* in *build.gradle* (as described [here](https://gist.github.com/ramonaharrison/7a2061bf5ee920dfff53b37ed83520ec))
So in the root *build.gradle* file I have the following:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

def localProperties = new Properties()
if (project.rootProject.file('local.properties').canRead()) {
    localProperties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())
}

buildscript {

    ext {
        ...
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In module's *build.gradle* file I have the following:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN", localProperties['token']
    }
}
```

But after sync I get the following error:

> Could not get unknown property 'localProperties' for
>   DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, ...} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

Where am I wrong? How to solve this problem?

Comment: That error looks like it is coming from some other location than this file, such as a reference to `localProperties` in the `defaultConfig` closure in a module's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I've updated the post - added module's build.gradle file content

Comment: AFAIK, `localProperties` as you have declared it is local to that `build.gradle` file. Try defining it on `ext`.

Answer (score 0):

I met some problem. Variable `localProperties` is not builtin but defined by yourself. You may add

```
Properties localProperties = new Properties()
    File file = project.rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (file.exists()) {
        localProperties.load(file.newDataInputStream())
    }
```

to you build.gradle in the defaultConfig block.

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle under "android" section you need to add

```
android {
def localProperties = new Properties()
localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("local.properties")))
...}
```